# Modeling the number of corners in soccer

Tags: machine-learning, forecasting, maximum-likelihood, negative-binomial-distribution, poisson-process

For a project, I am looking for idea to model for the distribution of corners in football matches. I know that the number of goals can be model by a Poisson distribution, but for the number of corners, the distribution has
 larger tails. I think it is partly due to the fact that after a corner, the ball is put back in the game on one extrema of the field and this makes the probability of a second corner more likely. Would any of you have an idea of a model I could use?

**Precisions on the model I plan to use**
My initial idea  is to adapt the [Maher Model](http://www.90minut.pl/misc/maher.pdf) for the number of goals in soccer matches.  In this model the number of corners of scored by team $T$ when playing vs team $T'$ is assumed to follow a Poisson distribution with Parameter $a_T d_{T'}$ where $a_T$ and $d_T$ are the attack and defense scores of team $T$ which are estimated from the data using maximum likelihood.

I am looking for a distribution different from the Poisson distribution (fatter tails) which generalizes the Maher model to the distribution of corners. A distribution for which estimating the parameters via maximal likelihood is possible would be perfect.

Comment: You can try negative binomial distribution. It has the property of overdispersion (large right tail).

Comment: No simple distribution will be an exact match. Do you particularly need a specific distribution for something? There are a number of heavier-tailed distributions that might be a reasonable approximation. I'd probably start with a negative binomial if it was actually necessary to have one at all.

Comment: Sure, but that is just a starting point for your creative process. In your place, I would try negative binomial regression, then play with a mixture of distributions, perhaps.

Comment: I just edited the initial message with more precisions